# Logarithmic Function for Drop Rates in a Game

Tags: logarithms

I'm a a Game Volunteer of a legacy game that the community does not let die yet, haha.

As a community, we're encountering a problem when it comes to deciding what will be a good idea for a "pet" to actually increase drop rates in the game.

The game is an MMORPG and there are monsters around that drop items.

This is the situation:

There are items from 100% chance to drop to 0.01% chance to drop.

We are implementing a companion "pet" which in activation would increase the drop rate slightly based on the level of the "pet". Pet levels go from 0 - 43 at this moment.

Our server drop base is 2x. Which means that a base item with 20% chance drop, in our server drops 40% chance.

There is also a fruit that you eat and increase the chance either by 2x or 3x depending on the fruit.

So these are the variables:

1. Lvl of pet
2. fruit 2x or 3x
3. base drop of item
4. server drop rate

We would like to come up with a formula, probably logarithmic, so that the lower the chance of the item, the better the formula works for the item without taking benefit for higher chance drop items.

What we mean is that, **a 0.05% chance drop rate, will not have the same ratio that a 20% chance drop rate would have, but it would still increase the chances.**

How can we calculate all of these different variables without breaking the game and collapsing the economy?

Breaking the game would be:

Right now, let's say that we have a

- 10% chance drop rate for X item.
- with fruit: that goes to 20% chance of X to drop.
- with server rate: goes to 40% chance of X to drop.
- with lv43 pet (max level of pet): ???? of X to drop.

vs

- 0.05% chance drop rate for Y item.
- with fruit: that goes to 0.10% chance of Y to drop.
- with server rate: goes to 0.20% chance of Y to drop.
- with lv43 pet (max level of pet): ???? of Y to drop.

**We want to benefit Y more than X, but still increase its chances.**

Thank you in advance. This would help so many people and a lot of headaches.

Comment: It's impossible for anybody unfamiliar with the game to answer this question adequately.

Comment: @lightxbulb I really don't think it's that hard considering that I've given all the variables for it. And I'm here to answer all other doubts about it and factors that I might not be considering. Thank you for the reply though.

Comment: You may not think, but with the information you have provided, this is infeasible: "How can we calculate all of these different variables without breaking the game and collapsing the economy?". I believe other users will agree with me. So I recommend that you formalize your question.

Comment: @lightxbulb i will do my sir, i will refactor the question

Comment: @lightxbulb hopefully that will give some insight on what the purpose of the question is, thank you for your input. I would love to see your answer too :)